# How to peek through imported packages in Golang

Tags: go

Programming languages such as Javascript allow you to peek through a library/package by just passing the package into `console.log()`.  I tried doing the same in Go, but that did not work.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "os"


func main() {
    fmt.Print(os)
}
```

Is this not the right approach?

Comment: Go does not allow you to do this. You can use a package like [`go/types`](https://godoc.org/go/types) to examine the source of a package to list exported variables, functions, etc.

Comment: Are you familar with [godoc](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc)?

Comment: why the down vote. this is a legit question for someone coming from another language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) when you use something like `const assert = require('assert');` you are importing `object` which was exported from `assert` script.

But in [[image]go](/questions/tagged/go) `import` it's something like namespace which you're going to use in your package. And that's why you just can't do what you wish, because namespace it is not object instance.

You can create object instance from `os` package and inspect it like in your example with `console.log()`, it should looks like:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    ps := os.ProcessState{}
    fmt.Printf("%+v", ps)
}
```

With purpose to inspect whole `os` package you can check https://golang.org/pkg/os/, here you can find all info about go packages (functions, structures, methods, constants, etc).